# Windows boot partition missing after Kali Linux installation

Tags: partition, windows, kali-linux, gparted

[Windows 10 User Installed Kali 2.0]

This seems to be the issue of many beginner users of Kali Sana. Installing Kali and either formating their windows partitions not making windows bootable any more or setting up kali in a means that windows partitions aren't easily accessible.

I think I have done the 1st of the 2 formatted my drive because I don't see it any where when searching Gparted in kali.

If there is a way to recover my windows that would be a blessing. Only directions I have seen that look like they may be useful are the installation of software like rEFind and Fixparts.

Comment: Kali is for security professionals, they don't make that kind of mistake, you should look at using another linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I almost installed an update of `GRUB` (Linux bootloader) on top of my Windows bootloader. This would make Windows unbootable. If this is your case, then data from the Windows partition is recoverable either by copying the data from within Kali, or by using the Windows install disk to repair the installation (have you tried that?).

If you have indeed formatted the Windows partition, you can either try to recover the data yourself by using the software you mentioned, or by handing the hard drive over to a data recovery company. The thing is that the more you write on top of the former Windows partition, the less data it will be possible to recover.

Comment: Xavras Wyzryn So far I have been trying to get the "apt-get install update" to run properly. So the answer to have I tried the software or a recovery method is no, not yet. A little more detail about the install, it was my second time installing from a bootable usb so I thought I knew what I was doing. When asked what drive to save partition to I chose the main hard drive. That's why I think I may have formated the drive. I am going to try to get the rEFind to work 1st then try to recover if that doesn't work. It's been 3 days so I hope I haven't lost to much of my windows files.

Comment: It's only showing 2 partitions the extended partition isn't shown. I can get rEFind to install or run. So Looks Like I am on the recovery route. I'll let you know the out come asap

Comment: do you have any idea what to do when this happens trying to install rEFind.                                                                                                                                                                                         ShimSource is none
Installing rEFInd on Linux....
The ESP doesn't seem to be mounted! Trying to find it....
// doesn't seem to be on a VFAT filesystem. The ESP must be
mounted at //boot or //boot/efi and it must be VFAT! Aborting!

Comment: @Thenuub: Instead of using rEFInd, have you tried entering BIOS at startup and selecting manually a partition to boot from?